# Solana Error: Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token

Tags: web3js, solana

I minted token with my web3js script and received such warning in Solana explorer:

**Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token. Verify the token's mint address to ensure it is correct.**

https://explorer.solana.com/address/DgpDPmAHE7bpgjEG8TksyqiKszoLAFWrrKa3MzNW8d3n?cluster=devnet

Token names and logos are unique:
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmdL6fLjXTp7xRtXCKP9MdyyJhvQGm5emphCnmRe57AGNB

What is wrong with this token?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Solana Explorer source code to see what triggers this warning https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/explorer/src/pages/AccountDetailsPage.tsx#L210=

Tokens are considered verified only if part of the [spl-token-registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token-registry). However, this repository has recently been deprecated in favour of Metaplex token metadata standard.

Comment: Thanks! How do I register a new token in Solana now?

Comment: You can refer to the `Adding a new token` section of the [spl-token-registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token-registry) for this https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list#adding-a-new-token

Comment: I have already tried to work with metaplex. Buddy, write a working example in JS with metaplex if you know. It is necessary to register an existing token. Thank you.